# How to get the definition of a macro as a string literal?

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

Say in a header, which I do not want to read myself but which I do include, I have

```
#define A B
#define B C
```

Now

```
#define STR(name) # name
```

defines a macro that gives me the name of any macro as a string, and

```
#define EXP_STR(name) STR(name)
```

defines a macro that gives me the full expansion of any macro as a string. So

```
cout << STR(A) << EXP_STR(A) << endl;
```

will print `AC`.

Is there any way to get `"B"` from `A` using some macros?

Comment: I'm not sure. I believe this isn't possible due to how token expansion in C works. This is a very good question.

Comment: It's an excelent question, but I am almost sure that this is not possible, hope someone knows if it is, and if not then a good explanation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Avoiding a double macro subsitution in the C pre-processor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27533994/avoiding-a-double-macro-subsitution-in-the-c-pre-processor)

Answer (score 1):

Since you can write

```
#define B C
#define A B

#define STR(name) # name
#define EXP_STR(name) STR(name)
```

and the

```
cout << STR(A) << EXP_STR(A) << endl;
```

will output exaclty the same, it means that it's not possible.

When you do this

```
#define A B
```

and then

```
#define B C
```

now this means that `A` will be substituted by `C` and not `B`, so there will be no way to do it because when the `cout` line is reached the preprocessor had already substituted `A` by `C`.

So the short answer is, **it's not possible** because the preprocessor would have replaced `A` with `C` before the file is compiled.

Comment: Note that the line `#define A B` does **not** define A to be C, only because B is defined to be C. If I do `#undef B`, `#define B X`, and then `cout << STR(A) << " " << EXP_STR(A) << endl;`, the output will be AX. Expansion is done when the macro is "called" not when it is defined. Some languages ([make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Flavors.html)) can not even decide for them self which way to do it.

Comment: @not-a-user I posted my answer before I saw your comment, but I do provide a nice way to do this...

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's possible. You just have to use a couple of cheats.

- `#undef B` before `#define EXP_STR`
- Use a few more levels of indirection

For example:

```
#define A B
#define B C

#define _TEMP_VAR B    // so that it can be redefined later
#undef B               // so that EXP_STR(A) will return "B"

#define EXP_STR__(x) (x)
#define EXP_STR_(x)  EXP_STR__(#x)
#define EXP_STR(x)   EXP_STR_(x)

#define STR(x) # x

#define B _TEMP_VAR    // now you can still access A normally, defined to B (defined to C)
```

A test program to prove it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf( "EXP_STR(A) = %s\n", EXP_STR(A) );
    printf( "STR(A)     = %s\n", STR(A) );
}
```

Output:

```
EXP_STR(A) = B
STR(A)     = A
```

Comment: Could you clarify this a little? Do we have to do all this code for every macro we want to be able to print? Or just once?

Comment: @Vality Define macros you want to use `EXP_STR` on before the `#define _TEMP_VAR`.

Comment: The macros `EXP_STR__` and `EXP_STR_` are not needed. You get exactly the same by `#define EXP_STR(x) (STR(x))`.

Comment: `#define _TEMP_VAR B` and `#define B _TEMP_VAR` are not needed. You get exectly the same without them, because you have `#undef B`.

Comment: "now you can still access A normally, defined to B (defined to C)" - That is wrong. Adding `int C = 42; printf("A = %d\n", A);` will give a compilation error (because `B` is not declared) instead of printing `42`.

Comment: I think the main misunderstanding is that `#define B C` followed by `#define _TEMP_VAR B` does **not** define `_TEMP_VAR` to expand to `C`. (Macros are processed only when they are used in the proper C code, not when their name appears in another macro definition. And the `#undef B` breaks al connections between `_TEMP_VAR` and `C` whatsoever.)